# How to fix "/etc/apt/sources.list" could not be read error?

Tags: sudo, software-sources

I tried to reinstall **sopcast** with the following command:

```
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

but nothing happened, then I try the next command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys CD30EE56
```

and I get the following error:

```
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 60 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: i have ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 6):

You have appended the second command to the `sources.list` with `tee`. Edit your `sources.list` with `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`. Remove the `sudo ...` line (you should find it at the end) save and exit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Then update your sources with `sudo apt-get update` and you should be fine again.

If you delete the `sources.list` while editing ths `sources.list`.Open the terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and become root by typing `sudo -s` and `cd /etc/apt` and then check the file `sources.list.distUpgrade` then type `cp sources.list.distUpgrade sources.list` that's all.

Then update your sources with `sudo apt-get update` and it should be fixed.

Comment: Hey German thanks for your answer!When i write " sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list. " it opens the file on terminal but there is nothing there,how i can read the file?the note in the end of the page doesn't help

Comment: try again without the dot at the end: "sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list"